# Find all paths from root to leaves in a part of tree that stored in database

Tags: sql-server, tree

Assume a tree that stored in the database (MS SQL Server) in following structure

```
CREATE TABLE Nodes(
   NodeId int PRIMARY KEY, 
   NodeValue varchar(50));

CREATE TABLE Adjacencies(
   ParentId int REFERENCES Nodes(NodeId), 
   -- every adjacence is unique for specified child node
   ChildId int PRIMARY KEY REFERENCES Nodes(NodeId), 
   Weight int);
```

And now we have a table *Foo* that used values in this tree (with relationship *many-to-many*)

```
CREATE TABLE Foo(FooId int PRIMARY KEY);
CREATE TABLE Foo_Nodes(
   FooId int REFERENCES Foo(FooId), 
   NodeId int REFERENCES Nodes(NodeId),
   CONSTRAINT PK_Foo_Nodes PRIMARY KEY (FooId,NodeId))
```

Now for specified *FooId* we have subset of tree nodes, (in *FooNodes* table) and our task is to find all "root-leaf" paths from this subset (this subset not necessary still would tree, rather it would be set of subtrees).

Is there the best way to do this using SQL syntax?

The result table for paths `{{1,2,3}, {1,4}, {5,6}, {9}}` for example can have structure like this

```
PathId    NodeId    Level
---------------------------
1         1         1       |
1         2         2       | first path
1         3         3       |
2         1         1           | second path
2         4         2           |
3         5         1                | third path
3         6         2                |
4         9         1                      | fourth path
```

P.S. This task is rather obvious in imperative languages: we just need to enumerate all "root-leaf" paths in all resulted subtrees and union these sets of paths.

Comment: is there a maximum depth? do we need to detect and deal with loops?

Comment: @JonKloske what kind of loop do you mean? This is a tree that by definition have no loop.

Comment: Oh, sorry, didn't spot the "PRIMARY KEY" on the ChildId in Adjacencies! Scratch that concern; just the one about depth. If you know there's a maximum depth (n) you may be able to do this with (n) joins, otherwise I know of no way to do what you're after (though that's not to say a way doesn't exist, of course!)